# Outputting int but carrying a decimal

Tags: java

So I have a piece of code where I want to output the seconds as an integer, but I don't want to lose the decimal value as I need to use it as part of the count in a for loop to code the program correctly, here is the code (for loop is unfinished obviously as there is no count)

```
         System.out.println("Recommended Splits for Marathon for time of "
 + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

            hoursInSeconds = hours * 3600;
                minutesInSeconds = minutes * 60;
                totalTime = hoursInSeconds + minutesInSeconds + seconds;
                double totalSecondsPerKM = totalTime/42;
                int hoursPerKM =   (int) (totalSecondsPerKM/3600);
                double remainderHours = totalSecondsPerKM%3600;
                int minutesPerKM =  (int) (totalSecondsPerKM/60);
                double secondsPerKM = (totalSecondsPerKM%60);


            for (int index = 1; index <=42; index++){
                System.out.print(index + " ");





                System.out.print("" +hoursPerKM);
                System.out.print("");
                System.out.print(":"+minutesPerKM);
                System.out.print("");
                System.out.print(":"+secondsPerKM);
                System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Do you want the value to be rounded or truncated?  Have your tried using `System.out.print(":"+(int)secondsPerKM);`?

Comment: Ah right that'd probably work! That's just for the output? so having the double in my code wouldn't effect that i'm assuming?

Comment: Since it's not assigning the result back to anything (that you're using), then no, it won't effect the original value

Comment: ^ how would you go about rounding it up in the output though?

Comment: If the problem is only the print of the variable, another option that you have is to use ``System.out.format`` instead of  ``System.out.print``. Thus you can specify how many decimal cases you want to print.

Comment: I just want "System.out.print(":"+secondsPerKM);" this output to be outputted as an int but the calculations done as a double

Comment: ^ and the int also to be rounded up

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", 1.6));
```

or

```
System.out.println((int)1.6);
```

The first will round the value, output `2`, the second will truncate it, outputting `1`

Comment: System.out.print(":"+secondsPerKM);

so in regards to that line of code, how would i format it so it rounds up?

Comment: In my first example, replace `1.6` with `secondsPerKM`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yep, some result, I tend to use `String.format` more then `printf` just because that's what I need to use :P